# Rails - HABTM association, checking exists? of any object in array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I want to check the existence of any HABTM relationships in an array and return true if any exist.

At present, the only way I can see to do this is:

```
result = false
[1,2,3,4].each do |i|
  if user.parents.exists?(i)
    result = true
    break
  end
end
```

I tried passing in an array as follows, but I get an exception

```
result = true if user.parents.exists?([1,2,3,4])

NoMethodError: undefined method `include?` for 1:Fixnum
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[1,2,3,4].inject(false) {|res, i| res ||= user.parents.exists?(i)}
```

Pretty much the same logic,  just more ruby-ish code using inject syntax.

**UPDATE:**

Haven't tested it. but this might also work:

```
user.parents.exists?(:id => [1,2,3,4])
```

Comment: The updated version worked. I much prefer that over using inject, much more readable. Thanks =]